How to change docker config SecurityOptions with colima start --edit
TLDR; How do I disable apparmor in Security Options using colima start --edit (I see it enabled when running docker info on my host mac)?
I am experiencing a failing container when using colima, but when I run with docker desktop the container works fine. I think I have narrowed it down to a permissions issue when mounting directories. What I would like to do in Colima is set the docker config to match the working docker desktop scenario to see if that is the issue.
running docker info in working scenario (docker desktop):
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: unconfined
  cgroupns

running docker info in colima:
 Security Options:
  apparmor  <-- I want to remove this
  seccomp
   Profile: unconfined
  cgroupns

How can I edit the colima config template to indicate apparmor is disabled?
My current config in the template file (when I run colima start --edit) is:
docker:
seccomp-profile: unconfined

I have tried using apparmor: false but this doesn't work.
